# Python Import "from sys import argvs" give error

Tags: python

I am a new Python user, and would really appreciate some help. My code is as follows:

```
from sys import argvs
script, mum_mood, dad_mood = argvs
```

my own function

```
def dad_and_mum_mood(mum_mood, dad_mood):
    print "If both mum and dad are in a good mood, all is good."
    print "If one is and one isn't, all is good."
    print "If both are in a bad mood, not so good."
    print "Mum is in a %s mood" % (mum_mood)
    print "Dad is in a %s mood" % (dad_mood)
    print "Where does that leave us?"
```

?

```
dad_and_mum_mood(mum_mood, dad_mood)
```

I am just trying to get get the information `mum_mood` and `dad_mood` from the `argv`s (written into the command line), but I get the error `ImportError: cannot import name argvs`.

Do you have any idea why this wouldn't be working? Thank you so much for helping me.

Kind regards

Answer (score 4):

Did you mean `from sys import argv`, i.e. `argv`, not `argvs`? Check out the [`sys` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html), `argv` is the first entry.

For a powerful command line argument handling module I recommend you check out [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html), which is part of the standard library.

Answer (score 4):

If you have trouble with a module in Python, use `dir` and `help` to find your way around:

```
>>> import sys
>>> help(sys)
>>> dir(sys)
```

You'll find that the name you are trying to import is not `argvs`, but just `argv`.